# Auto-select first <select> option when loading async options in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

I have a `<select>` HTML element which I want to `v-model` bind to a `ref` value in Vue.js 3's `setup()` method. So when a user selects a different option, the `Form.ProductID` ref updates.

Here is the `<select>` code:

```
<select v-model="Form.ProductID" id="ProductID" name="ProductID">
  <option value="1">Option A</option>
  <option value="2">Option B</option>
  <option value="3">Option C</option>
</select>
```

And `setup()`:

```
export default {
  name: "ComponentProductSelector",
  setup() {
    const Form = ref({
      ProductID: '2',
      Price: null,
      Currency: null
    })

    onMounted(() => Form.value.ProductID)
    document.querySelector("#ProductID option:first-of-type")
  }
}
```

On first load in vue devtools, it shows the data as being:

```
Form (Object Ref) 
    ProductID: "[object HTMLOptionElement]"
```

When I select an option in the `<select>` element, `Form.ProductID` updates as expected and shows which option I selected e.g.:

```
 Form (Object Ref) 
        ProductID: 3
```

The problem is that on the page first load, the `<select>` element is not selecting the option with `value="2"` even though I am hard coding it in the `setup()`. It just shows a blank option! However if I change the `<select>` element to the following code then it does:

```
<select ref="Form.ProductID" id="ProductID" name="ProductID">
  <option value="1">Option A</option>
  <option value="2">Option B</option>
  <option value="3">Option C</option>
</select>
```

Now the option with `value="2"` is selected by default when the component is rendered, however the actual value of `Form.ProductID` does not update and vue devtools continues to show `ProductID: "[object HTMLOptionElement]"` as the data.

How can I get the `<select>` element to work using `v-model` and also select a default option when the component loads?

Comment: There must be a different problem, that should work  https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/zrj18f69/

Comment: @shob you're right, it was a piece of code doing this: `onMounted(() => Form.value.ProductID = document.querySelector("#ProductID option:first-of-type")` to make the first option selected by default. Is it possible to make `Form.value.ProductID` equal to the value of the first option onMounted?

Comment: Why not set `Form.ProductID` to 1?

Comment: @shob because i cannot always know what the IDs will be. they will eventually come from a database as json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the updated question in comments about how to select the first option when async loading.  Once the data is loaded, set the value of `Form` to the first item in the options array (cloned to avoid mutating it), rather than manually manipulating the input DOM.

For example:

```html
<select v-model="Form.ProductID" id="ProductID" name="ProductID" v-if="options">
  <option v-for="option in options" :key="option.ProductID" :value="option.ProductID">
    {{ option.ProductID }}
  </option>
</select>
```

```js
setup() {
  const options = ref(null);
  const Form = ref(null);

  axios.get('...').then(response => {
    options.value = response.data;
    Form.value = { ...options.value[0] };    // Clone and select first option
  });
  return { options, Form }
}
```

There's a `v-if` on the `<select>` to delay its rendering until the data is ready.

Here's a demo:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const options = ref(null);
    const Form = ref(null);
    
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(response => {
      options.value = response.data;
      Form.value = { ...options.value[0] };    // Clone and select first option
    });
    return { options, Form }
  }
});
app.mount("#app");
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="Form.id" id="ProductID" name="ProductID" v-if="options">
    <option v-for="option in options" :key="option.id" :value="option.id">
      {{ option.id }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios"></script>
```

Comment: You're welcome!  I made a small update.  It's important to clone the option first, or create a fresh object for `Form` and add properties one by one, cloning any reference types.  Otherwise changing form inputs would change the option data for option #1